# Wordpress home page redirected you too many time error after just change FTP server

Tags: wordpress

I changed my wordpress website FTP server.
Then admin page is running but home is taken by ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
This is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sourcier/wp/cms_xji2ha0lan/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sourcier/wp/cms_xji2ha0lan/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And also I added below code into wp-config.php.

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');
```

Comment: Did you try changing the RewriteBase to `/cms_xji2ha0lan/`

Comment: yeah, I have changed also. But It isn't really working. I have no opinion why it has occured.wp-config.php has no problem at all